# segmentation fault and argv, argc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, command-line-arguments

I made a code that prints out the input:

```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%c", *argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

When I put something like `ab`, `abcdef`, `ac`, `*cf`, it works well, but when I put `**` or `$$` it returns 2, and when I put `$a`, `$k`, and so on, it generates segmentation error. I wonder why it doesn't print out the letters that I put.

Comment: `*` and `$` are handled by the shell even before your program is invoked. You might consider RTFM for `sh`, `ksh`, `csh`, `bash`, `dash` or whatever shell you are using.

Comment: Print also `argc`, then check if it is legal to print `argv`[**1**].

Comment: *"when I put '**' or '$$'"* How do you *"put"*? If it's truly command-line, maybe you should try to see what `'**'` or `'$$'` mean. Try `echo **` or `echo $$` for instance

Comment: Run in a debugger, and when the crash happens see what the values of `argc` and `argv[1]` are.

Comment: Try surrounding those arguments in double quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're running Linux or some other kind of UNIX flavour, `$a` refers to the environment variable a. This is expanded by your shell, and since you didn't set it to a value, it becomes empty.

To get the literal string `$a`, you'll have to escape your argument - depending on the shell you're using, you could try single or double quotes or escaping the `$` with a backslash `\`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use Linux/Unix/MacOs. Instead of running your program try echo $$ or echo $1. These system variables are expanded to other strings (or not expanded at all). So you'll get the expanded texts or a segmentation fault when there is none.